# How to simulate IPhone apps just like we emulate Android apps For GNU/Linux

Tags: ios, iphone

how to simulate IPhone applications just like we emulate Android applications. For GNU/Linux

Comment: Please explain in detail what you've tried and where you'll need help. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Xcode comes with an iOS Simulator which opens automatically, when you click the "Run"-button

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you mean emulate. What is your purpose?

If you want to develop and test an app you are better of running mac os through a VM and install Xcode.

If you just want to test the app I would advise to download iOS Simulator or Smartface on windows. It's not the best option for debugging...

Comment: Why would I need a VM for macOS to simulate an iOS app? What is Smartface, and what advantage does it have over using the iOS Simulator that comes for free with Xcode?

Comment: Last time I check Xcode wasn't available for windows.

Comment: Hmm, the question does not mention Windows at all ...

Comment: I just assumed even if he is using a mac he'd have to pay for a Developer account

Comment: That is not true anymore. You can download and use the Xcode tools without a paid membership, and use them to develop and test your (personal) apps, see for example https://blog.ionicframework.com/deploying-to-a-device-without-an-apple-developer-account/.

Comment: Just checked... My bad...

Comment: still to run it on Linux he'll need a VM

Comment: Actually it's not supported by Apple, and not permitted by their license.